# Not able to get the object value in nested array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to get the object value in nested array object using JavaScript. If `sourcecountry` matches the country in object, it should return the payment service.

I have tried this:

```
funtion getValue(source, ob){
      var list  = obj.filter((cn)=>{
      return cn.country_from.filter((c)=>{
       return c.country == source
      })
   })
}
var result = getValue(sourcecountry, obj);


var sourcecountry = "SG";
var obj = [
    {
     "country_from": [
            {
                "country": "SG",
                "payment_service": [
                    {
                        "type": "bank transfer",
                         "speed": {
                          "unit": "days",
                         "number": "2"
                     },
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "country": "TH",
                "payment_service": [
                    {
                        "type": "credit",
                         "speed": {
                          "unit": "days",
                          "number": "1"
                      },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Expected Output:

```
Speed: 2 Days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the code below. You only need 1 `.filter()` not 2. You can make the outer one a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var sourcecountry = "SG";
var obj = [{
  "country_from": [{
      "country": "SG",
      "payment_service": [{
        "type": "bank transfer",
        "speed": "2 days"
      }]
    },
    {
      "country": "TH",
      "payment_service": [{
        "type": "credit",
        "speed": "1 day"
      }]
    }
  ]
}];
var result = getValue(sourcecountry, obj);
console.log(result);

function getValue(source, ob) {
  var list;
  ob.forEach((cn) => {
    list = cn.country_from.filter((c) => {
      return c.country == source;
    });
  })
  return `Speed: ${list[0].payment_service[0].speed}`;
}
```